# Not able to install any package on NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-start

[image]Please find the attached image , am not able to install any package on NPM. i did try setting & resetting proxy with "http" & "https". both are not working for me. so kindly please help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your firewall or something blocks all the requests , because even ping doesn't work

Comment: You can try to run tracert ip and find out where the request is rejected